# Transforming image from Web Mercator Projection to Simple Cylindrical (Plate Carree) projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, web-mercator

I have an image that is projected using the Web Mercator projection.

Does anybody know how to transform (in ArcMap) this image from the Web Mercator projection to the Simple Cylindrical (Plate Carree) projection?

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110011/transforming-image-from-web-mercator-projection-to-simple-cylindrical-plate-car#comment155188_110011), you can do this using the [Project Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project-raster.htm) tool which:

> Transforms the raster dataset from one projection to another.